# Porque JButton me retorna null? Java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing, jbutton

```
public class PacienteControl  implements ActionListener{...

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println(pacienteVista.RegistrarBtn);

        if(e.getSource().equals(pacienteVista.RegistrarBtn)) {

            String identificacion = pacienteVista.IdentificacionTxt.getText();
            String nombres = pacienteVista.NombresTxt.getText();
            String apellidos = pacienteVista.ApellidosTxt.getText();
            SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
            String fechaNam = formato.format(pacienteVista.FechaNacimientoDte.getDate());
            String sexo = null;
            sexo = (pacienteVista.MasculinoOpt.isSelected() == true)? "m" : "f" ;
            pacienteModelo = new modelo.Paciente(identificacion, nombres, apellidos, fechaNam, sexo);
            gestorPacienteModelo.RegistrarPaciente(pacienteModelo);
        }
```

---

```
public class RegPacienteInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    public JButton RegistrarBtn;
    public JButton NuevoBtn;
    public JTextField IdentificacionTxt;....

public RegPacienteInternalFrame() {

        pacienteControlador = new controlador.PacienteControl(this);...

        JButton RegistrarBtn = new JButton("Registrar");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_RegistrarBtn = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_RegistrarBtn.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_RegistrarBtn.gridx = 1;
        gbc_RegistrarBtn.gridy = 7;
        RegistrarBtn.addActionListener(pacienteControlador);
        getContentPane().add(RegistrarBtn, gbc_RegistrarBtn);


        JButton NuevoBtn = new JButton("Nuevo");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_NuevoBtn = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_NuevoBtn.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_NuevoBtn.gridx = 2;
        gbc_NuevoBtn.gridy = 7;
        NuevoBtn.addActionListener(pacienteControlador);
        getContentPane().add(NuevoBtn, gbc_NuevoBtn);
    }
```

Ninguno de estos dos botones funciona :/
Ambos me retornan `null`

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenés que borrar el "JButton" en esta parte: `JButton RegistrarBtn = new JButton("Registrar");`. Sino estás creando otro objeto dentro del constructor en vez de instanciar el público, y al llamar al método `equals()` sobre este último, se produce una NullPointerException.

Comment: Sino estás creando otro objeto dentro del constructor en vez de instanciar el público.

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/161607)

Comment: ¿Cómo que no? Devuelve **null** porque no instancia el objeto que después compara en la clase **PacienteControl**.